# IrNet implementation - how to give a py program a required argument

Tags: python, github

I'm trying to use IrNet using a github repository. In the instructions it says I need to run a command `python run_sample.py` to make it work. I have obviously cloned the repo into my google colab but then after running this command line it throws me an error `run_sample.py: error: the following arguments are required: --voc12_root`. After checking this `run_sample.py` I can see that the program requires a path  `parser.add_argument("--voc12_root", required=True, type=str, help="Path to VOC 2012 Devkit, must contain ./JPEGImages as subdirectory.")`, however I simply do not know how to satisfy this requirement. Where and how to paste it?

I'm trying to use this repo: https://github.com/jiwoon-ahn/irn

Here is the program I'm trying to run:

```
import argparse
import os

from misc import pyutils

if __name__ == '__main__':

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # Environment
    parser.add_argument("--num_workers", default=os.cpu_count()//2, type=int)
    parser.add_argument("--voc12_root", required=True, type=str,
                        help="Path to VOC 2012 Devkit, must contain ./JPEGImages as subdirectory.")

    # Dataset
    parser.add_argument("--train_list", default="voc12/train_aug.txt", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--val_list", default="voc12/val.txt", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--infer_list", default="voc12/train.txt", type=str,
                        help="voc12/train_aug.txt to train a fully supervised model, "
                             "voc12/train.txt or voc12/val.txt to quickly check the quality of the labels.")
    parser.add_argument("--chainer_eval_set", default="train", type=str)

    # Class Activation Map
    parser.add_argument("--cam_network", default="net.resnet50_cam", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--cam_crop_size", default=512, type=int)
    parser.add_argument("--cam_batch_size", default=16, type=int)
    parser.add_argument("--cam_num_epoches", default=5, type=int)
    parser.add_argument("--cam_learning_rate", default=0.1, type=float)
    parser.add_argument("--cam_weight_decay", default=1e-4, type=float)
    parser.add_argument("--cam_eval_thres", default=0.15, type=float)
    parser.add_argument("--cam_scales", default=(1.0, 0.5, 1.5, 2.0),
                        help="Multi-scale inferences")

    # Mining Inter-pixel Relations
    parser.add_argument("--conf_fg_thres", default=0.30, type=float)
    parser.add_argument("--conf_bg_thres", default=0.05, type=float)

    # Inter-pixel Relation Network (IRNet)
    parser.add_argument("--irn_network", default="net.resnet50_irn", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--irn_crop_size", default=512, type=int)
    parser.add_argument("--irn_batch_size", default=32, type=int)
    parser.add_argument("--irn_num_epoches", default=3, type=int)
    parser.add_argument("--irn_learning_rate", default=0.1, type=float)
    parser.add_argument("--irn_weight_decay", default=1e-4, type=float)

    # Random Walk Params
    parser.add_argument("--beta", default=10)
    parser.add_argument("--exp_times", default=8,
                        help="Hyper-parameter that controls the number of random walk iterations,"
                             "The random walk is performed 2^{exp_times}.")
    parser.add_argument("--ins_seg_bg_thres", default=0.25)
    parser.add_argument("--sem_seg_bg_thres", default=0.25)

    # Output Path
    parser.add_argument("--log_name", default="sample_train_eval", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--cam_weights_name", default="sess/res50_cam.pth", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--irn_weights_name", default="sess/res50_irn.pth", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--cam_out_dir", default="result/cam", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--ir_label_out_dir", default="result/ir_label", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--sem_seg_out_dir", default="result/sem_seg", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("--ins_seg_out_dir", default="result/ins_seg", type=str)

    # Step
    parser.add_argument("--train_cam_pass", default=True)
    parser.add_argument("--make_cam_pass", default=True)
    parser.add_argument("--eval_cam_pass", default=True)
    parser.add_argument("--cam_to_ir_label_pass", default=True)
    parser.add_argument("--train_irn_pass", default=True)
    parser.add_argument("--make_ins_seg_pass", default=True)
    parser.add_argument("--eval_ins_seg_pass", default=True)
    parser.add_argument("--make_sem_seg_pass", default=True)
    parser.add_argument("--eval_sem_seg_pass", default=True)

    args = parser.parse_args()

    os.makedirs("sess", exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(args.cam_out_dir, exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(args.ir_label_out_dir, exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(args.sem_seg_out_dir, exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(args.ins_seg_out_dir, exist_ok=True)

    pyutils.Logger(args.log_name + '.log')
    print(vars(args))

    if args.train_cam_pass is True:
        import step.train_cam

        timer = pyutils.Timer('step.train_cam:')
        step.train_cam.run(args)

    if args.make_cam_pass is True:
        import step.make_cam

        timer = pyutils.Timer('step.make_cam:')
        step.make_cam.run(args)

    if args.eval_cam_pass is True:
        import step.eval_cam

        timer = pyutils.Timer('step.eval_cam:')
        step.eval_cam.run(args)

    if args.cam_to_ir_label_pass is True:
        import step.cam_to_ir_label

        timer = pyutils.Timer('step.cam_to_ir_label:')
        step.cam_to_ir_label.run(args)

    if args.train_irn_pass is True:
        import step.train_irn

        timer = pyutils.Timer('step.train_irn:')
        step.train_irn.run(args)

    if args.make_ins_seg_pass is True:
        import step.make_ins_seg_labels

        timer = pyutils.Timer('step.make_ins_seg_labels:')
        step.make_ins_seg_labels.run(args)

    if args.eval_ins_seg_pass is True:
        import step.eval_ins_seg

        timer = pyutils.Timer('step.eval_ins_seg:')
        step.eval_ins_seg.run(args)

    if args.make_sem_seg_pass is True:
        import step.make_sem_seg_labels

        timer = pyutils.Timer('step.make_sem_seg_labels:')
        step.make_sem_seg_labels.run(args)

    if args.eval_sem_seg_pass is True:
        import step.eval_sem_seg

        timer = pyutils.Timer('step.eval_sem_seg:')
        step.eval_sem_seg.run(args)
```

I'd be grateful on any suggestions how to deal with that issue. It seems like a simple thing "run this and here you go, the program's ready to work", but I've been struggling with it the whole day with no satisfactory result.

Thanks, Joanna

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the parameters when running the program. This is, when running `python run_sample.py`. The help from that parameter says that you need to include the **Path to VOC 2012 Devkit**.

Your call should look something like this:

```sh
python run_sample.py --voc12_root 'path/to/your/VOC2012'
```

Comment: It does work, thank you! If I wanted to give the function more arguments, should I just separate them with a space?

Comment: Yes, some parameters do not need an argument (the argument in this case is `'path/to/yout/VOC2012'`). If your argument contains spaces you can surround it with single or double quotes `'` so that it knows it is all part of the same argument.